# convert date in yyyymmdd format in BQ (standard)

Tags: google-bigquery

Platform: BigQuery (standard)

I have a partitioned table by day (table_name_20180101), and I am trying to write a query so that, any given day, it only works on the previous 7 days tables.

(So, for example, today I would want to have it running on: table_name_20180607, table_name_20180608, all the way to _20180613)

I was trying to reach this result through a syntax like

```
FROM
`table_name_*` where _table_suffix > (tables up to 7 days ago)
```

Does anyone have advices about how to obtain this?
I thought try convrerting Current_Date() in YYYYMMDD format, and then subtract 7, but I am not managing to get it.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```
FROM `table_name_*` 
WHERE _table_suffix > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

in case if you need to exclude current day you can use

```
FROM `table_name_*` 
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN 
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_SUB` with the format below to achieve a dynamic look back window, here's an example for a rolling 7 days:

```
FROM `mydata.ga_sessions_20*`
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 7 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
```

This was built for using on GA exported tables in BigQuery, but your date format appears to be the same, so it should be fine.